How can I achieve a SIP client that works behind a NAT using PJSAU2 and Python?
I'm currently working on a SIP client using python and the python bindings for pjsua2 (pjsip) and I'm running into the issue, that calls behind NAT are able to send all SIP messages but fail in sending the RTP packets. I know that I can fix this issue by doing some port forwarding on the router, but I would like to have an option not requireing any further configuration on my network.
I've already done port forwarding and then it is working but as mentioned before I don't like this option, further I had a look at the MicroSIP client and tried to understand their code, but I couldn't find my answers there. The only info I have is, that they somehow managed to achieve what I'm trying. So how did they achieve this / what are my options here?
